# Submit a CheckBox generados dinámicamente en ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estoy tratando de enviar un modelo que tiene una lista de `CheckBox` a un controlador pero no no estoy obteniendo los valores:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="tableSections">
        <tbody>
            @for (var index = 0; index < Model.anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList.Count; index++ )
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[index].CodSecRep)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[index].IdCtaAnaSin)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[index].IdRepAnaSin)
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[index].BSecDisp)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[index].BSecDisp, 
                                            Model.anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[index].TxDescSecRep)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

El HTML que se genera es:

```
<form action="/Cuentas/ConfigurationReport/SaveConfigReport" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-failure="onFailureFormSaveConfigReport" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="onSuccessFormSaveConfigReport" id="FormConfigReport" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="OgTElcNJVXowlUWtjZDHDdhvDmsIa9PBUjOvgS2QKAB7_rEUKYjKQsRYkBypDmBoVrUoGFmc3eRI6b-SIIYA2A1appYq_VISEfX_hwDygZakfkfpKawYLMfFQG0bwb_d0Lo3GA2"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field IdCtaAnaSin must be a number." data-val-required="El campo IdCtaAnaSin es obligatorio." id="IdCtaAnaSin" name="IdCtaAnaSin" type="hidden" value="0"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field IdRepAnaSin must be a number." data-val-required="El campo IdRepAnaSin es obligatorio." id="IdRepAnaSin" name="IdRepAnaSin" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="hidden_TipoReporte" name="anaSinConfiguracionReporte.CodTypeReport" type="hidden" value="TR_BAS"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field IdRepAnaSinCompare must be a number." data-val-required="El campo IdRepAnaSinCompare es obligatorio." id="hidden_ComparacionReporte" name="anaSinConfiguracionReporte.IdRepAnaSinCompare" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="anaSinConfiguracionReporte_ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList" name="anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList" type="hidden" value="System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[Lms.AnalizadorSiniestralidad.Entities.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDto]"><div class="row CommonInterface_Section">
<div class="row CommonInterface_SectionTitle">
    <span id="lblTipoReporte">Tipo de Reporte</span>
</div>
<div class="row CommonInterface_Section">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2  CommonInterface_LabelControl">
        <span id="lblTipo">Tipo:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <select id="drpTipoReporte" class="valid">
                <option value="TR_BAS">Basico</option>
                <option value="TR_COM">Comparativo</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="pnlReporteComparativo" style="display: none;">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  CommonInterface_LabelControl">
            <span>Reporte de comparación:</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-5">
            <select id="drpReporte"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row CommonInterface_SectionTitle">
    <span>Secciones Disponibles</span>
</div>
<div class="row CommonInterface_Section" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="tableSections">
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="anaSinConfiguracionReporte_ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList_0__CodSecRep" name="anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[0].CodSecRep" type="hidden" value="BALANCE_GENERAL">
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field IdCtaAnaSin must be a number." data-val-required="El campo IdCtaAnaSin es obligatorio." id="anaSinConfiguracionReporte_ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList_0__IdCtaAnaSin" name="anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[0].IdCtaAnaSin" type="hidden" value="0">
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field IdRepAnaSin must be a number." data-val-required="El campo IdRepAnaSin es obligatorio." id="anaSinConfiguracionReporte_ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList_0__IdRepAnaSin" name="anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[0].IdRepAnaSin" type="hidden" value="0">
                        <input class="check-box valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo BSecDisp es obligatorio." id="anaSinConfiguracionReporte_ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList_0__BSecDisp" name="anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[0].BSecDisp" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[0].BSecDisp" type="hidden" value="true">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="anaSinConfiguracionReporte_ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList_0__BSecDisp">Balance General</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="CommonInterface_ButtonSection">
        <input type="button" id="btnGenerarReporte" class="ResourceButton_GenerateReport" value="Genera Reporte" onclick="sendDataForm()">

    <input type="button" id="btnRegresar" class="ResourceButton_Return">
</div>
```

Mi controlador con el `Action` es el siguiente, la lista dentro del modelo siempre viene con 0 items:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SaveConfigReport (NuevaCargaArchivoViewModel model, CaseResponseDto caseResponseDto )
    {
        IEnumerable<string> businessExceptionArray = null;
        RasSecRepAnaSinBl rasSecRepAnaSinBl = new RasSecRepAnaSinBl();
        businessExceptionArray = rasSecRepAnaSinBl.InsertOrUpdate(model.anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList);

        if ( null != businessExceptionArray )
        {
            caseResponseDto.ValBool = !IS_GENERATE_REPORT;
            caseResponseDto.Error = true;
            caseResponseDto.Titulo = TITLE_ERROR;
            caseResponseDto.Mensaje = string.Format(MESSAGE_ERROR, businessExceptionArray.ElementAt(0));
        }
        else
        {
            caseResponseDto.ValBool = IS_GENERATE_REPORT;
            caseResponseDto.Error = false;
            caseResponseDto.Titulo = TITLE_SUCCESSFULL;
            caseResponseDto.Mensaje = MESSAGE_SUCCESSFULL;
        }

        return Json(caseResponseDto);
    }
```

Comment: hola bienvenid@ a SOes, podrías colocar el HTML generador por favor? También subir nuevamente la imagen que se ve borrosa. Saludos

Comment: Te agradecería mucho si te tomas el tiempo de copiar y pegar el HTML generado, luego selecciona el código y presiona este boton { } para darle el formato adecuado. Si necesitas ayuda con los formatos, hay varios usuarios que aportamos en ello :D

Comment: olvidé mencionar que el HTML que vayas a colocar, que tenga todo el formulario, y los JavaScript que utilices.

Comment: @fredyfx Sí, pero estaría bueno que suba una parte solamente, porque de otro modo se volvería repetitivo.

Answer (score 0):

El `html` tiene tu `input` con su propiedad.

```
 name = anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[0].IdCtaAnaSin
```

Lo que necesitas es que cada `name` sea incremental para cada `input`. Por ejemplo:

```
anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[0].IdCtaAnaSin
anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[1].IdCtaAnaSin
anaSinConfiguracionReporte.ExpRasSecRepAnaSinDtoList[2].IdCtaAnaSin
```

... etc.

Con eso ya el `controller` agarra tu lista que envíes.